# Piping into a command

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

There is a way to pipe into a command?

For example:

On one folder I have 2 files:

1. filesnames
2. file1

filesnames contains:

```
file1
```

file1 contains:

```
11
22
33
44
11
```

And when I run the command (on the same folder that contains filesname and file1):

```
ls -l | grep 11
```

Or the command:

```
cat filesname | grep 11
```

It doesn't return:

```
11
11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When thing are piped to `grep`, it is interpreted as *text* to be processed, not *filename* to be processed.

Backquotes can run a command and return text for another command.

Solution 1:

`` grep 11 `ls`
grep 11 `cat filesname` ``

I leave out `-l` as only the file names are needed, not the file metadata.

`xargs` is another way:

Solution 2:

`ls | xargs grep 11
cat filesname | xargs grep 11`

Comment: Try this with filenames that have spaces, or worse, wildcards (or, even worse, space-surrounded wildcards) in their names. It's not a reliable practice, and we shouldn't be teaching it: More of the [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) entries are related to side effects of unquoted expansion than any other single cause.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for pointing out that. I have edited my answer. Will these commands be less problematic?

Comment: `xargs` can certainly be *made* less problematic, using `-d $'\n'` or `-0` (with NUL-delimited inputs). See my comment on Andrew Sun's answer, and the link therein.

Comment: This command was works, thanks! but how do I print the output without the name of the file at the beginning of every line?

Comment: @user3383886 use `grep -h` instead of `grep`. `-h` here means --no-filename. See more in `man grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `grep 11` command will filter all lines that you pass to it and only display the ones containing `11`. If you run the same commands without the `grep 11` part you will see there isn't any containing `11`, therefore the behaviour is correct.

On the other hand, doing `cat filesname | grep 11` is a waste of time. `grep` can accept files as arguments, so you can do `grep 11 filesname` directly.

Comment: I think he is trying to grep `file1`, instead of `filesname`. But the name `file1` is not given, but written in `filesname`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) utility.

```
cat filesname | xargs grep 11
```

Or more simply, without the useless use of cat:

```
xargs grep 11 < filesname
```

This will run `grep 11 <line>` on every line in filesname. Since your lines are file names, this will run `grep 11 file1`.

Comment: If it's one filename per line, `xargs -d $'\n' grep 11` is better form... or, to support BSD systems as well as GNU, `tr '\n' '\0' <filesname | xargs -0 grep 11`. See the warnings about `xargs` in [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-)